# Copy-and-update semantics and performance in F# record types

Tags: performance, f#, record

I am experimenting with a settings object that is passed on through a bunch of functions (a bit like a stack). It has quite a few fields (mixed ints, enums, DU's, strings) and I was wondering what the best data type is for this task (I have come back to this a few times in the past few years...).

While I currently employ a home-grown data type, it is slow and not thread-safe, so I am looking into a more logical choice and decided to experiment with record types.

Since they use copy-and-update semantics, it seems logical to think the F# compiler is smart enough to update only the necessary data and leave non-mutated data alone, considering it is immutable anyway.

So I ran a couple of tests and expected to see a performance improvement between full-copy (each field is updated) and one-field copy (one field is updated). But I am not sure I am using the proper approach for testing, or whether other datatypes may be more suitable.

As an actual example, let's take an XML qualified name. They have a small local part and a prefix (which can be ignored) and a long namespace part. The namespace is mostly the same, so only the local part needs updating.

```
type RecQName = { Ns :string; Prefix :string; Name :string }

// full update
let f a b c = { Ns = a; Prefix = b; Name = c}
let g() = f "http://test/is/a/long/name/here/and/there" "xs" "value"

// partial update
let test = g();;
let h a b = {a with Name = b }
let k() = h test "newname"
```

With timings on, in FSI (set to Release, x64 and Debug off) I get (running each twice):

```
> for i in 0 .. 100000000 do g() |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.412, CPU: 00:00:01.404, GC gen0: 637, gen1: 1, gen2: 1

> for i in 0 .. 100000000 do g() |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.317, CPU: 00:00:01.310, GC gen0: 636, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

> for i in 0 .. 100000000 do k() |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.191, CPU: 00:00:01.185, GC gen0: 636, gen1: 1, gen2: 0

> for i in 0 .. 100000000 do k() |> ignore;;
Real: 00:00:01.099, CPU: 00:00:01.092, GC gen0: 636, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Now I know timings are not everything, and there's a clear difference of roughly 20%, but that seems to small to justify the change, and may well because of other reasons (the CLI may intern the strings, for instance).

Am I making the wrong assumptions? I googled for record-type performance, but they were all about comparing them with structs. Does anybody know of the algorithm used for copy-and-update? Any thoughts on whether this datatype or something else is a smarter choice (given many fields, not just three as above, and wanting to use immutability without locking with copy-and-update).

### Update 1

The test above doesn't really test anything, it seems, as can be shown with the next test.

```
type Rec = { A: int; B: int; C: int; D: int; E: int};;

// full
let f a b c d e = { A = a; B = b; C = c; D = d; E = e }

// partial
let temp = f 1 2 3 4 5
let g b = { temp with B = b }

// perf tests (subtract is necessary or the compiler optimizes them away)
let mutable res = 0;;
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do f i (i-1) (i-2) (i-3) (i-4) |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do g i |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b
```

Results:

```
> for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do f i (i-1) (i-2) (i-3) (i-4) |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b ;;
Real: 00:00:09.039, CPU: 00:00:09.032, GC gen0: 6358, gen1: 1, gen2: 0

> for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do g i |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b;;
Real: 00:00:10.571, CPU: 00:00:10.576, GC gen0: 6358, gen1: 2, gen2: 0
```

Now the difference, while unexpected, shows. Looks like the copying is definitely not faster than not copying. The overhead of copying in this case may be due to the extra stack slot required, I don't know.

At the very least it shows that no magic goes on (as Fyodor already mentioned in the comments).

### Update 2

Ok, one more update. If I inline both `f` and `g` functions above, the timings become remarkably different, in favor of the partial-update. Apparently, the inlining has the effect that either the compiler or the JIT "knows" it doesn't have to do a full copy, or it is just the effect of putting everything on the stack (the JIT or compiler getting rid of the boxing), as can be seen for 0 GC collections.

```
> for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do f i (i-1) (i-2) (i-3) (i-4) |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b ;;
Real: 00:00:08.885, CPU: 00:00:08.876, GC gen0: 6359, gen1: 1, gen2: 1

> for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do g i |> function { B = b } -> if b < 1000 then res <- b ;;
Real: 00:00:00.571, CPU: 00:00:00.561, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Whether this holds in the "real world" is debatable and should (of course) be tested. Whether this improvement has any relation to record types, I doubt it.

Comment: Records are nothing more than .NET classes with readonly properties and a constructor (plus some extra stuff like comparison). There is no special "algorithm" for copying them, they simply copy every field, one by one. To achieve better performance, you need to break up the big flat structure into several substructures, which may themselves consist of substructures, effectively forming kind of a tree. Then the non-modified substructures will be reused while copying, thus saving on their reallocation.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, thanks, and slightly disappointing. I updated with a different test, which seems to illustrate your point. I thought I read somewhere that the copy-and-update was copying only modified data, but I can't recall where (of if it was even F#). A simple tree approach is what we currently use, though sub-optimal, so maybe I should just improve the approach we have

Comment: If you want smart copying semantics in a key-value structure, try the `PersistentHashMap` data structure from [FSharpx.Collections](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/). It's an implementation of Clojure's map structure, which uses structural sharing to copy only a few items each time you produce a new map. It sounds like that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @rmunn, thanks, that looks promising. I will experiment a bit with it.